# Pigeonhole question - divisibility by chosen number

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, pigeonhole-principle, natural-numbers

This question should be solved with pigeonhole principle.

Let $a,n \in \mathbb N$ such that $a$ is a number whose digits are only $3$'s and $0$'s, and $n$ is an unspecified natural number.

Show that there is some number $a$ such that $a$ is divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the pigeonholes are the $n$ possible remainders upon division by $n$.  Now you just need to choose appropriate pigeons, and demonstrate that a collision will get you the desired property.

Comment: here's what I tried: I looked at the sequence $a_i = 333...3$ $i$ times, the number $3$ is written $i$ times. if we divide it by $n$ we get: $a_i = n*q_i+r_i$ where $0 \leq r_i < n$ but what now?

Comment: Good start.  Suppose $a_i, a_j$ have the same remainder.  What can you say about $a_i-a_j$?

Comment: Ahhh brilliant! Thanks. But wait, who says that for $i \neq j$ its even possible that $a_i$ and $a_j$ have the same remainder? Answer for myself: pidgeonhole. if i goes up to n+1 we can use it.